# How to evaluate o model that predicts probabilities for a game between two players

Tags: regression, classification, modeling, model-evaluation

I have a theoretical question.

Let's say we have a game that is based on time (duration `T`) (something like football or basketball), and two players play each other.
The task is to find a model that predicts each time the winner A or B (it predicts probabilities).
For example:

```
At time 0: A: 0.65 B:0.35  (based on time, score, momentum etc)
....
At time t: A:  p   B: 1-p  
....
At time T: A: 1    B: 0   (A won)
```

How could we evaluate such a model? And furthermore, if we need to evaluate the model on many games, not just one, how would this be applied?

The only solution I think is relevant is [Brier Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score), but I am not sure how would I apply it to 100 different games (let's say, entire league) in order to calculate a single score.

Comment: I would evaluate any such model on the basis of how it is intended to be applied.  For instance, if it is to be used for a betting scheme, then the issue would be the relative effect on betting strategies and returns when it is used compared to when it is not used.  If instead it is used to make coaching decisions, then it would be evaluated in an entirely different manner--based on some measure of improvement in expected numbers of wins, for instance.  Therefore it behooves you to edit your post with an explanation of how you plan to apply the model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I need to evaluate the predictive capabilities. The probabilities be as close to real probabilities as i can, and all i know is the final outcome of the game at the end of te T. Letw say that model 1 predicts player A: 0.65 (at t= 1), 0.55 (t=10)... Etc and model 2 for the same player/times 0.64, ...0.57... etc... Player A won, how should i measure and evaluate thse two models